# Can I Use Arduino Libraries in STM-IDE?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, embedded, programming, arduino-uno

I am fairly new to programming microcontrollers and I want to know if I can import libraries, that are written for Arduino, in other IDEs such as STM32CubeIDE.

For example can I use the library HX711, which is used to read data from load cell, in STM32CubeIDE?

Comment: Go look at HX711 source code and you will find different HALs for it, there exists a HAL for STM32 already.

Comment: Ah, yeah it already has. But I was thinking about other peripherals also which do not have HAL for STM32..

Comment: Then implement every piece of Arduino API on STM32 that is required to run the libraries. But such thing may already exist as isn't Arduino platform already implemented on several MCUs, including STM32?

Comment: And what about for other IDEs/Microcontrollers such as CH551G? Which do not have so well established platforms and environments?

Comment: Maybe I'll have to learn how to write a library from scratch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not, as Arduino libraries tend to target some oddities of the Arduino environment and its way of grouping things *before* feeding them to the C++ compiler (eg, even if you were using avr-gcc's g++, the build process for Arduino does some unusual things first)

You can however work through the source code of Arduino libraries and manually translate them into standard C++ conventions for file interaction (or with more effort, C), and make them use whatever backend I/O and support capabilities are available on your board.

There also exist Arduino BSP's for a number of STM32 MCU's which can be added as plug-ins to the Arduino IDE, or used with various other Arduino-capable build platforms like Platform-IO.  However sometimes these still require some library improvement - for example ATmega Arduino's have fixed SPI and I2C pins, but on most STM32's you have choices, which need to be communicated somehow.